# Como usar o p:messages do Primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

Defini o campo `nome` usando `p:inputText` para receber valores, ele é um campo *obrigatório*. Como faço para exibir uma mensagem mostrando que esse campo é obrigatório, usando `p:messages`? Também estou utilizando JSF.

Segue meu HTML:

```xml
<h:form>
        <p:messages/>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Cadastro de Pessoas
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
            <p:inputText id="nome" required="true"/>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                 iconPos="right"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Segue a imagem do Formulário:

<kbd>[image: Formulário]</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Já tentou utilizar um `p:message` só pro componente `p:inputText`?

Ficaria assim:

```
<h:form>
    <p:messages/>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Cadastro de Pessoas
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" required="true"/>
        <p:message for="nome" />

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                             iconPos="right"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Creio que dessa forma funcione.

Abraços.

Comment: Não, infelizmente não deu certo.

Comment: O que aconteceu após as alterações? Deu erro ou não mudou nada no fluxo?

Answer (score 3):

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Cadastro de Pessoas
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
    <p:inputText id="nome" required="true" requiredMessage="O campo nome é obrigatório"/>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                         iconPos="right" action="seuManagedBean.metodo()" update="@form"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Com o atributo "requiredMessage" voce pode custom a mensagem de cada campo. Se voce tiver 10 campos requeridos e todos não forem preenchidos, a mensagem de todos eles vai aparecer somente no p:messages , sendo assim suas mensagens de erro ou alerta fica em um só lugar.